# JS code doesnt work in Jquery in nested function construction

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Edit:**

Still, I am waiting answer.I wanted notice that the question is still active issue.

---

I have below JS code and it works good:

```
function CommentStyle2() {
  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
    const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');

    if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {
      node.style.setProperty ("color", "green", "important");
    }
  });
}

window.onload = CommentStyle2;
```

---

I wrote it in Jquery function like this:

```
window.console = window.console || (function(){
    var c = {}; c.log = c.warn = c.debug = c.info = c.error = c.time = c.dir = c.profile = c.clear = c.exception = c.trace = c.assert = function(){};
    return c;
})();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict"

    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');

        if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

    $("ul.colors .color1" ).on('click', function(){
        alert("1Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        node.style.setProperty ("color", "red", "important");
        return false;
    });

    $("ul.colors .color2" ).on('click', function(){ 
        alert("2Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        node.style.setProperty ("color", "pink", "important");
        return false;
    });

}
}


    $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
        if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "-195px"
            });
        }
    })

    $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })

});
```

---

In 2. code, only alerts work, the colors dont change.Why?

Also I want to learn the syntax and full information about Javascript.Where can I learn it?

I mean serious guide.It will be official website or extencive e-book.

Comment: I suggest you look at https://javascript.info or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript for `JavaScript` related content.

Comment: @goto1 I look at that 2 website just now, there is no full methods in them.I want to access all information about JS, not simple tutorials.Is there any index or 600-700 pages e-book?

Comment: You could read the specs if you’d like - https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/

Comment: @goto1 Thanks, the link is what I want about the learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be working?
The click binding only occurs if an element's style is color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)'.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict"

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
    const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');

    if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

      $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
        alert("1Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");
        return false;
      });

      $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
        alert("2Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        node.style.setProperty("color", "pink", "important");
        return false;
      });

    }

    $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
      if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
        $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
          left: "0px"
        });
      } else {
        $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
          left: "-195px"
        });
      }
    })

    $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="color: rgb(22, 160, 133)">123</div>
<ul class="colors"><li class="color1">1</li></ul>
<ul class="colors"><li class="color2">2</li></ul>
```